# What is the point of inter-species specific quorum-sensing?

Tags: bacteriology, molecular-evolution, quorum-sensing

So apparently, according to [this](https://www.ted.com/talks/bonnie_bassler_on_how_bacteria_communicate) TED video, there is a kind of quorum sensing involving a universal, inter-species specific molecule that all bacteria secrete. Is there any evidence of bacteria being able to examine levels of other species-specific bacteria, rather than just any bacteria that can secrete that universal peptide? It just seems like its not enough to generally survey the amount of ANY bacteria in relation to that of your own species.

Comment: All bacteria is most certainly wrong.